# Unreadable values in heatmap

Tags: python, heatmap

I have a dataframe `df` containing numeric values 1432,22390,43223 and so on...
When I try to plot it using a heatmap like this 
`sns.heatmap(df[cols].transpose(), annot=True)`
I'm getting these unreadble values 2.2e+04, 1.7e+03 etc.
The thing is that in another notebook I'm using the same code and it works perfectly.
So what is the problem?

Comment: What is unreadable about floating point numbers?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you mean. Usually, if I have a value, let's say 230, when I plot it in the heatmap with the 'annot' set to true, I can see my 230 in the plot. While here I Can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set `annot=True`, the default param `fmt='.2g'` is being applied (i.e, it is going to round each number to 2 significant digits and then formats the result in either fixed-point format or in scientific notation, depending on its magnitude).
To have the general format, you simply change `fmt='.2g'` to `fmt='g'`.

Here you can find more information about [formats](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

Comment: I didn't know the role of that param, and since I had other examples without defining it I didn't pay him any attention.
Thanks for the brief and concise explanation.